# Override PDF tax settings

Tags: magento-1.7, php

We override the Mage_Tax_Model_Config to have different tax settings for specific customer groups. Everything went well except for the PDF documents.

We checked the current customer group ID with $customer->getGroupId() where $customer is Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();

Why this is don't work on the PDF documents? Please see the override class in detail:

```
public function displaySalesPricesInclTax($store = null)
{
    $customer = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getGroupId() > 1) {
        return false;       
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public function displaySalesPricesExclTax($store = null)
{
    $customer = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getGroupId() > 1) {
        return true;        
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The customer helper class method is

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    if (empty($this->_customer)) {
        $this->_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    }
    return $this->_customer;
}
```

The pdfs are normally only created in the back-end so you would not be working with a customer session. And if I am not mistaken the default Magento pdfs simply do not provide a way to change the price display to be tax inclusive or tax exclusive to start with.

Comment: I was going to mention the same thing about the customer session not being available in the backend where PDFs are created. If the PDFs are not updated when adjusting config settings at `tax/sales/display` then that should be something I would hope would be fixed, or a separate section in `tax/sales` for PDF settings.